# What's wrong I did to send a batch request to google?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, okhttp

I tried to send a batch request to Google with OkHttp, but I always received error 500 and Unknown Error in response.

This is my code, the token is get from GoogleAuthUtil.

```
    MultipartBuilder multipartBuilder = new MultipartBuilder();
    MediaType http = MediaType.parse("application/http");
    MediaType mixed = MediaType.parse("multipart/mixed");
    multipartBuilder.addPart(RequestBody.create(http, "GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages"));
    multipartBuilder.type(mixed);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://www.googleapis.com/batch")
            .header("Authorization", " Bearer " + token)
            .post(multipartBuilder.build())
            .build();

    try{
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String res = response.body().string();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this problem. All the code has no problem besides one line:

```
multipartBuilder.addPart(RequestBody.create(http, "GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages"));
```

It should be convert to byte[] first and call the similar method later and do not forget the \n.

```
byte[] request = (https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages).getBytes();
RequestBody partRequest = RequestBody.create(HTTP, request);
```

I find out the problem in the OkHttp source code.

```
public static RequestBody create(MediaType contentType, String content) {
  Charset charset = Util.UTF_8;
  if (contentType != null) {
    charset = contentType.charset();
    if (charset == null) {
      charset = Util.UTF_8;
      contentType = MediaType.parse(contentType + "; charset=utf-8");
    }
  }
  byte[] bytes = content.getBytes(charset);
  return create(contentType, bytes);
}
```

The problem is the charset to be added to Content-Type. It makes the 500 error.